# How to print the entire shell command line?

Tags: bash, command-line

The below code prints the command line for simple case, for example, `./x.sh 1234`.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$0 $@"
```

If I invoke it with `e=1 ./x.sh 1234`, then `e=1` is missing.
Is there a way to print the entire command line?

Comment: `e=1` is  not a cmdline argument but an env variable you're setting (that's available only for that script). If you want to pass an *argument*, put it alongside the other arg: `./x.sh 1234 e=1`.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question then. Is there a way to print out the command line with environment variables only available to the script? I'd like to filter out those global environment variables.

Comment: It's possible with some non-standard/portable hacks. To do that, you need to compare the script's environment with its parent's and get the diff. On Linux, you can get the parent's environment variables via `/proc/$PPID/environ`.

Comment: Note that `/proc/*/environ` may not reflect changes made during the lifetime of the process, such as `export FOO=bar` in bash, and the process might be dead by the time you inspect it.

Comment: @P.P: Nice idea. To play around in the script: `cat /proc/$PPID/environ /proc/$$/environ | tr '\0' '\n' | sort | uniq -u`

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on P.P's comment:

```
$ cat envtest
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Cyrus' idea:

cat /proc/$PPID/environ /proc/$$/environ | tr '\0' '\n' | sort | uniq -u

echo "#########################"

# only those in local environ

comm -13 <(cat /proc/$PPID/environ | tr '\0' '\n' | sort) <(cat /proc/$$/environ | tr '\0' '\n' | sort )

$ unset e
$ e=1 ./envtest
PS1=
SHLVL=1
SHLVL=2
e=1
#########################
SHLVL=2
_=/usr/bin/comm
e=1
```

Comment: One could append the following: `| grep -zvE '^(COLUMNS|LINES|OLDPWD|SHLVL|PS|_)='`

Comment: On a CentOS stream system, there are a lot of changed environment variables between $PPID and $$, such as `HISTSIZE`, `HISTCONTROL`, `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, etc.